# coefficient of homology of configuration spaces over real projective spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homology, braid-groups, configuration-spaces

In the slides *[Characteristic Classes of Surface Bundles
and Configuration Spaces](http://www2.ims.nus.edu.sg/Programs/015homo/files/miguel.pdf)*, Miguel A. Xicot'encatl, page 38, what is the coefficient of the following homology?

[image]

Could the coefficient be an arbitrary field?

Comment: I would ask him.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Thanks, Prof. Muro! Could you ask Professor Miguel for some references of this result together?

Comment: Don't take my previous comment that literally. I was suggesting that you could ask him.

Comment: I would guess it would not be arbitrary. I would guess $\mathbb{F}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ coefficients as this is where $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is interesting.